# expected running time of the algorithm containing two recursive calls

Tags: algorithm, performance

```
Function(A, n)
/* A is an array of integers
/* random is a function that returns an integer between 1 and (in this case) n-1

    if(n<=1) then return (A[1])
    else
      x←0；
      for i←1 to n-1 do
         A[i]←A[i]-A[i+1]
         x←x+A[i]
      end
      k←Random(n-1)
      x←x+Function(A,k)
      x←x+Function(A,n-k)
      return(x)
    end
```

I do not understand why the worst case of this algorithm is when k=1 or n-1 and the best case is when k=n/2. How to make sure the expected running time of 2ET(n/2) is less than ET(n-1)?

Comment: Hint: do some algebra to work out (say) how many times `x←x+A[i]` is executed for a given N in the 3 cases that you identified.  (Simplify the algebra by making N a power of 2 ...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223411/expected-running-time-of-the-algorithm-containing-two-recursive-calls) recursion question

Comment: That is an old joke.  It was funny the *first* time ....

Comment: The code is not quicksort, but it has an identical recursive structure to quicksort. Correctly proving that quicksort (and hence your algorithm here) has expected running time O(n log n) is not so easy, but you can find the analysis is most introductory books on the analysis of algorithms. For the cases when k is always 1 or n-1, you can write the recurrence relation and go for there. Like quicksort, it results in O(n^2) runtime.

Comment: (The worst case and average case analysis can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Average-case_analysis)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has identical recursive structure to QuickSort.

So like QuickSort, The worst case (k is always 1, or k is always n-1) is O(n^2), and the average case is O(n log n).

The recurrence relation for the code in the worst case is

```
 T(n) = n + T(n-1)
```

(which solves to T(n)=O(n^2) using telescoping)

The recurrence relation for the expected running time of the code is:

```
 T(n) = n + sum(k=1..n-1)[T(k) + T(n-k)]/(n-1)
```

Note there's a sum, which computes the average runtime based on the random value k.

This is somewhat tricky to solve, but the analysis can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Using_recurrences